# What's causing `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`?

Tags: javascript

In following code, what's causing `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`?
When I moved `LeakMemory` & `function` on separate lines, `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` started appearing on the line which have `function`

```
<html>
        <head>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                function
                    LeakMemory
                    ()
                    {
                        
                    }
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <input type="button" value="Memory Leaking Insert" onclick="LeakMemory()" />
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: There isn't any issue. See: https://jsfiddle.net/a9xr9ucj/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you have some weird hidden character that was stripped by Stack Overflow when you copied & pasted the code? Because copy-pasting your code works for me.

Comment: Same here, when I copied the code back to `Net Beans` from `SO` it worked.